# iPad Displaying Website Differently

Tags: ipad, web

My site (http://thepearlguide.co.ug) displays so awkwardly on the iPad as compared to other tablets.

I have searched and tried different solutions with no success http://pixelproductionsinc.com/pixelblog/how-to-fix-background-image-scaling-on-ipad-safari-browser/

Please help.

Comment: are you saying it is awkward because the image repeats?

Comment: no, because the whole layout is lost, elements are thrown everywhere around the site, others are suggesting it's a problem with scaling down the background image but I have tried all solutions in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site is designed for PC not for iPad, Tablet or Phone. You have to design your site for all devices using responsive design.

Comment: I know, but tablets scale the site down and display it well, check it out on an android tablet for instance, it's displaying properly but iPad just goes way out of line.

Comment: Android Browser are similar to PC browser but iPad Broser are diffeent from regular browser.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. So I may have to do a custom css for iPad

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this site](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/).

You can add some css for only ipads using media queries and set the default zoom level to something that makes your site look right using a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 768, initial-scale=0.68, minimum-scale = 0.5,  maximum-scale = 1.25"/>
```

Comment: and that would also change styles for android tablets that are currently displaying the site well...

Comment: potentially, however most tablets or browsers that are already scaling the site are doing something just like this. Try it and see. I use this method all the time. If you are using some kind of server language, you could inspect the user agent and only add the meta tag to pages served to mobile Safari if that is a major concern.

Comment: It didn't work either, I may just have to resort to custom css which is a big task...